# Isolating variable in equation

Tags: linear-algebra

TLDR:
I need help to solve for $ c $ in this equation:

$$ s = \arccos(\frac{2c}{\sqrt{2} * \sqrt{c^2 + (-c)^2 + 1)}} $$

Hello,

For a hobby project I need a formula that take an angle $ s $ and a vector $ a $, and then return a vector $ b $ with the given angle $ s $ from the given vector $ a $. The z coordinate of the returned vector is known to always be 1, and the x and y coordinate are related like this: $x = -y$. The given vector $ a $ is also known, and is $ 1, -1, 0 $. I have found the formula for finding the angle between two vectors, and (hopefully) modified it to my above case. The (modified) formula is like this:

$$ s = \arccos(\frac{(x_a * c + y_a * (-c) + z_a * z_b)}{\sqrt{x_a^2 + y_a^2 + z_a^2} * \sqrt{c^2 + (-c)^2 + z_b^2}}) $$

where $ c $ represent the $ x = -y $ relation, which I need to solve for ($ c $, that is), and as mentioned, $ s $ is the angle between the vectors. I tried symbolab, which did not work. Then I tried by hand, but I struggled to isolate $ b $. In order to ease the job, I filled in the known numbers, which symbolab could not solve either.

Back to trying by hand. First filling in the known numbers:

$$ s = \arccos(\frac{(1 * c + (-1) * (-c) + 0 * 1)}{\sqrt{1^2 + (-1)^2 + 0^2)}* \sqrt{c^2 + (-c)^2 + 1^2}}) $$

Which can rudimentarily be shortened to

$$ s = \arccos(\frac{2c}{\sqrt{2} * \sqrt{c^2 + (-c)^2 + 1}}) $$

Moving $ cos $

$$ \cos(s) = \frac{2c}{\sqrt{2} * \sqrt{c^2 + (-c)^2 + 1}} $$

And from here I'm stuck. Because Symbolab could not solve it, I'm almost starting to think that I made a logical error somewhere, causing the equations to not be solvable. Can anyone help solve this equation, or see if I made an error?

Comment: The dot product between vectors $(1,-1,0)$ and $(c,-c,1)$ is $2c$, magnitudes of vectors are $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2c^2+1}$. I don't see any logical errors there.
So consider squaring both sides; $\cos(s)^2=\frac{2c^2}{2c^2+1}$, which gives $\sin(s)^2=\frac{1}{2c^2+1}$, then $c^2=\frac{1}{2\sin(s)^2}-\frac{1}{2}$ or $c^2=\frac{1}{2}\cot(s)^2$.

Comment: Thanks @Ally, works perfectly. Although I struggle to understand how squaring the equation gives $ \cos(s)^2=\frac{2c^2}{2c^2+1} $. When I try, I get $ \cos(s)^2=\frac{2c^2}{2*2c^2+1} $. How does the $ 2 $ in the divisor disappear? Also, how is $ \cos $ turned into $ \sin $? I tried searching around the web for a rule that explains how you rewrite the equation, but I can't find it/them.

Comment: Unfortunately, upon further inspection. it seems to not be working. The last two equations you provide do not equal the same result, when I try it out in symbolab.

Comment: If you want to determine a vector that has a specific angle, then better use a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions) which avoids all that mess.

Comment: Thanks @emacsdrivesmenuts. After spending about two hours brushing up my rusty matrice knowledge, I managed to solve my problem from your suggestion of rotation matrices, in a much more elegant manner than my original attempt.